# Ignore a file in current directory but exclude a directory with the same name

Tags: git

I have the following directory structure:

-- dir

---- dir/server (binary file)

---- dir/docker/server/Dockerfile

In my .gitignore I have the following:

```
 server
```

git is ignoring the sub dir `docker/server/Dockerfile` as well.

How Do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `dir/server`. The gitignore file looks for regex-like patterns, so it shouldn't ignore the `docker/server/*` files as they don't fit the previous pattern.